USB WebCam is not found when remotely accessed and locally logged out
I have a USB WebCam. I use the application cheese to see the camera feed. When I am logged in to the Linux machine locally (using a plugged-in monitor, keyboard, and mouse) everything works fine. Simultaneously, when I connect from a client to my Linux remotely using x2go, I can launch the cheese and see the camera feed.
But if I log out from the local workstation I will be out of luck. After launching the cheese in a terminal in x2go, it shows "No device found". As if the USB cable is unplugged.
I checked the command lsusb and I can see the camera listed:
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 1bcf:2284 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. NexiGo N930E FHD Webcam
Edit
Linux version: Xubuntu 20.04
Display server: X11
Display manager: lightdm
Desktop environment: xfce
What can I do?

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please edit your question and add information about your computer's OS. Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Also add in your question: if you are using wayland and xorg.

try using gstreamer maybe!!
